# Disabling Yum's PostInst RestoreCon Action

Tags: fedora, yum, selinux

When I update the package "selinux-policy-targeted" on a Fedora 15 box, as part of yum's post-inst action, a restorecon of the entire disk is called to change the on-disk selinux contexts to match the new rules. However, I have a server with a sizable disk array, with an extraordinary amount of small files, and there is a fairly high IO load most of the time, so this action takes an inordinately long time (read: literally multiple *days*) to perform this action.

Is there any way to force this restorecon to not take place, or at least let me exclude a directory tree from this action so I can update the OS's contexts for things that matter (i.e. configuration directories, etc) but not for my data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is option to exclude folder **(-e)** when you manually invoke the restorecon command, however when it is invoked automatically, it references the [restorecond.conf](http://selinuxproject.org/page/GlobalConfigurationFiles#.2Fetc.2Fselinux.2Frestorecond.conf_File) file and reapply the contexts. I suppose you have this large amount of data inside your user home directory, and the ~/* inclusion in the restorecond.conf will be the one that you need to tweak, as there is no option to exclude any folder via this conf, unfortunately.

Comment: :-/ Greaaaaat. I'm just using backuppc, which uses /var/lib/BackupPC/ as its home directory, and I'm backing up a few TB of machines to there. So, theoretically, any user of this software should be running into this issue as well. Damn.

Comment: You may want to relabel the fs with a different context if the /var/lib/BackupPC is mounted as a separate file system. Check: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=573447#c1 for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the same filesystem. I can at least fix it via changing my /etc/selinux/restorecond_user.conf, though. (Which contains your referenced ~/* line)

Comment: Nice, so it is fixed now.?

Answer (score 1):

The package doesn't do a complete relabel in %post, as that would be insane for lots of people ... it does:

```
restorecon -R /root /var/log /var/lock /var/run 2> /dev/null
```

...is there some reason that is including your backups?